# How do I mock a simple POST body when creating a test request

Tags: unit-testing, http, post, go

I'm trying to write a unit test for a simple form handler. I cannot find any info on how to create the form body in a way that it is being picked up by `r.ParseForm()` in my handler. I can see and read from the body myself, but `r.Form` in my test will always be `url.Values{}` when it works as expected in my application.

The code boils down to [the following example](https://play.golang.org/p/-M0BsArcEl):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httptest"

)

func main() {
    w := httptest.NewRecorder()
    r := httptest.NewRequest(http.MethodPost, "/", strings.NewReader("a=1&b=2"))
    handler(w, r)
}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    r.ParseForm()
    fmt.Printf("form: %#v\n", r.Form)
}
```

that prints

```
form: url.Values{}
```

when I'd expect it to print:

```
form: url.Values{"a": []string{"1"}, "b": []string{"2"}}
```

How do I actually pass the body to `httptest.NewRequest` so that it gets picked up by `r.ParseForm`?

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/KLhNHbbNWl

Comment: @mkopriva Ugh, I could have thought of that myself. Would you mind adding that as an answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You just need to set the `Content-Type` header on the request.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httptest"

)

func main() {
    w := httptest.NewRecorder()
    r := httptest.NewRequest(http.MethodPost, "/", strings.NewReader("a=1&b=2"))
    r.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    handler(w, r)
}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    r.ParseForm()
    fmt.Printf("form: %#v\n", r.Form)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/KLhNHbbNWl